# 1st order differential equation with x(t) and y(t) in one equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$y$ and $x$ are all in term of $t$ but after I have found the integrating factor and multiply is to the both side, then RHS will become $xe^{Rt/L}$ and don't know how to continue integrating the equation. 
[image]

Comment: Are $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ both to be determined?  Then you need more than one differential equation.  On the other hand, if $x(t)$ is assumed to be given (but not specified), then the best you can do is write down the solution as an integral involving $x(t)$.

Comment: the question said derived the general solution from the differential equation so if i just use x(t) then when i integrate the equation by parts then an derivative of x(t) will also produce, sorry if i confused u, i will edit the question with the whole original question

Comment: I have edit the question, could you help me with it? Thank you very much for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so $x(t)$ is assumed to be given.  Using the integrating factor, you get

$$ \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( e^{Rt/L} y(t) \right) = \dfrac{R}{L} e^{Rt/L} x(t)$$
which you integrate to get the general solution:
$$y(t) = \dfrac{R}{L} e^{-Rt/L} \left(\int e^{Rt/L} x(t)\; dt + C \right)$$
You can't really go any farther than that without being told what $x(t)$ is.
That's what happens in part (c).

Comment: Thank you so much:)) so for the condition, at t=0, x=1 and y=0, how could i put these conditions, must I integrate it first then put the conditions or put x=1 and then integrate the equation?

Comment: That's not what the condition in (c) says.  It says $y(0) = 0$, and
$x(t) = 1$ for $0 \le t \le 1$ while $x(t) = 0$ for $t > 1$.  The trick here is to solve it separately for the two cases $0 \le t \le 1$ and $t > 1$, and use the constant $C$ (which can be different in different intervals) so that the $y$ values match up where you go from one interval to the next.  Thus for $0 \le t \le 1$ you have $\int e^{Rt/L}\; dt + C = (L/R) e^{Rt/L} + C$ so
$y(t) = 1 + (CR/L) e^{-Rt/L}$.  To match the initial condition $y(0) = 0$ you take $C=-L/R$, so $y(t) = 1 - e^{-Rt/L}$.

Comment: That gives you $y(1) = 1 - e^{-R/L}$.  Now solve it in the interval $t > 1$ where $x(t) = 0$, and choose the $C$ for that interval to make $y(1) = 1 - e^{-R/L}$.